# Applying Hall's Theorem to a tripartite graph

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Hall's theorem works for bipartite graphs and shows there is a complete matching if Hall's condition holds. 
If I have a tripartite graph $(X,Y,Z,E)$ and Hall's condition holds from $X$ to $Y$ , from $X$ to $Z$ and from $Y$ to $Z$. Would this be a satisfactory condition to find a complete matching of "triangles" on $X$?

Comment: Take a hexagon $x_1y_1z_1x_2y_2z_2$ with $X=\{x_1,x_2\}$, $Y=\{y_1,y_2\}$, and $Z=\{z_1,z_2\}$.  I think Hall's condition holds for each pair of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$.  However, the graph is triangle-free.  You need something stronger.

Comment: Is it true when all three sets have two elements?

Comment: Yes if there is a correct compete matching from $X$ to $Z$.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not strong enough. Suppose $G$ is a cycle on $3n$ vertices; $n$ an integer satisfying $n \ge 2$ i.e., $V(G)= \mathbb{Z}/3n\mathbb{Z}$, and $i$ and $j$ are adjacent iff $i-j \equiv_3 1$. Then $G$ is tripartite w sides $X_0,X_1,X_2$; $X_i =\{j; j \equiv_3 i\}$. Can you see the rest from here.